# Requesting the authorization of 2 or more users for an action such as rm -rf to be taken

Tags: permissions, root

There is a team of 3 people that have a project. Decisions regarding the project are consensus-based. This team hosts an app on a Linux **vps**. The decision to uninstall the app from the server should only take place if all three members of the team agree. Is there a way, hardcoded at the OS level or software level, to enforce that the action to  `rm` the app (or `rm -rf` the directory) is approved by the three parties before execution?

**Maybe something like a "three factor authorization"?
Maybe something else?**

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing out of the box with linux. What you are trying to achieve, sounds more like wanting a tool like `Jenkins`. It's a 3rd party tool used for pipelines and automation. Jenkins can have nodes joined and take action on them. So what I would do, is join all VPS-es in Jenkins and write a simple pipeline, that requires the approval of some user or users, and after that happens it will execute. This is done with a Jenkins plugin called Input. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59411869) . I've done such things in the past and this will probably work for you. Plus, the pipelines actually execute shell commands on the nodes. You will also have a history on what's been deleted (in your example).

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing like that exists out of the box, but you can implement a policy using tools which drive your distro's package manager.

For example, for Debian, you can use e.g. `equivs` to manage a list of packages which needs to be installed on the system, and perhaps pair it with `deborphan` to remove unauthorized packages. If you keep their configuration files in version control, the VCS can be set up to require changes to be approved before they can be merged to the production branch.

Perhaps also look at tools like `cfengine` for managing host configurations.